# Gnome trash on cifs mount random behaviour

Tags: gnome, trash, cifs

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in Ubuntu 10.04. I have a cifs mount that's mounted by fstab as follows:

```
//192.168.1.1/share /media/storage    
cifs_netdev,username=guest,password="",uid=1000,guid=100,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I can mount the share using:

```
sudo mount -a
```

my user can then access it, create and delete files.  The deleted files appear in the gnome trash applet.  A folder `/media/storage/.Trash-1000` is created automatically.

When I log out, restart the machine and log in, the cifs share is mounted but the trash applet is empty.  If I unmount the share with `sudo umount /media/share` then remount with `sudo mount -a` the trash applet displays the contents of the `.trash-1000` folder!

It gets stranger...sometimes after `umount` then `mount -a` the trash is STILL empty, but another round of `umount` then `mount -a` fixes it.

It seems like the trash applet is "forgetting" to scan the `/media/storage` mount point and is not always finding the `.trash-1000` folder at that mount point.  Even when the trash applet is not displaying any trash from `/media/storage/.trash-1000` I can still delete things from the `/media/storage` and they're moved to the `.trash-1000` folder.

So I conclude there's a bug in the trash applet...anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards